# Braids of fibered knots

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, braid-groups

There are some theorems saying that the closure of a braid of a specific form is fibered. For instance, a theorem of Stallings says that the closure of a homogeneous braid is a fibered knot.

I am curious about the other direction:

> If $K$ is a fibered knot which is a closure of a braid $\beta$, then
> what can we say about $\beta$? Is there any structural theorem of
> fibered knots in terms of their braid words?

Any comment or suggestion about references will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this might be of interest: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.07445.pdf Section 7 has a discussion along the lines you are asking about.

Comment: Note that $\beta$ is fibered _with fiber surface equal to the surface given by Seifert's algorithm applied to $\beta$_ if and only if $\beta$ is homogeneous.

Also, this might interest you: https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09664